# How can I make when a client tries to subscribe to an unauthorized topic the client disconnects from the broker? I am using Dynamic Security Plugin

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, mqtt.js

Mosquitto congfig file:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
per_listener_settings false
plugin /usr/lib/mosquitto_dynamic_security.so
plugin_opt_config_file /mosquitto/config/dynamic-security.json
```

I need when a client tries to subscribe to an unauthorized topic the client disconnects from the broker

the broker doesn't deny the client subscribing to this unauthorized topic.

```
1689767044: Received SUBSCRIBE from testDyn1689766685806
1689767044:     asd/qw (QoS 0)
1689767044: Sending SUBACK to testDyn1689766685806
1689767044: Received PINGREQ from f676724b-e1d6-4770-b37c
1689767044: Sending PINGRESP to f676724b-e1d6-4770-b37c
1689767050: Denied PUBLISH from testDyn1689766685806 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'asd/as', ... (3 bytes))
1689767050: Denied PUBLISH from testDyn1689766685806 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'asd/as', ... (3 bytes))
```

Comment: The new log doesn't show anything useful, it says that a SUBACK packet was sent, but the debug output doesn't show what was in it, and we don't know what the client did with that SUBACK packet, but the logs show the behaviour that I described. Also Subscribing to a topic is totally separate to trying to publish to a topic, just because a client can not subscribe may not mean they can not publish to the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, they just don't get any messages for things they are not authorised for.

The broker will respond to the SUBSCRIBE packet with a SUBACK packet which will include information about if the client has succeeded in being granted the subscription. It's also worth noting that a subscription may succeed but still not receive any messages because it contains a wildcard, but all the messages are on a topic that while covered by the wildcard a more focuses ACL entry denies the client.

Depending on which client library you are using the client may get a callback that informs it what topics it has been granted.

Comment: Please check this video!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C2FPgIXH-fCWuFN5F0ujOkEdGSNfndLO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And why would/should I do that?

Comment: This video has a real example of "when a client tries to subscribe to an unauthorized topic the client disconnects from the broker"

Comment: If you have more details, edit the original question, but don't expect people to follow random links to things on Google Drive...